# Invalid command 'PerlLoadModule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: apache, svn

Installed Redmine, configured automatic repository svn creation for this projects.
But when i restart httpd service, this erro happend.

```
[root@iZ23lttzrggZ config]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 42 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:
Invalid command 'PerlLoadModule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

This my PerlLoadModule file:

```
PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine
<Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath "/opt/repositories/svn"
        SVNListParentPath on
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Satisfy any
        LimitXMLRequestBody 0
        SVNPathAuthz off
        PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
        PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion Repository"
        Require valid-user
        RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine_db;host=localhost:3306"
        RedmineDbUser "redmine_admin"
        RedmineDbPass "**********"
</Location>
```

Comment: Did you load the corresponding apache modules ? `sudo a2enmod dav`,
`sudo a2enmod dav_svn`, `sudo a2enmod perl` ? [source](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Repositories_access_control_with_apache_mod_dav_svn_and_mod_perl)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had deleted the error modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install -y epel-release

yum install -y mod_perl
```

Answer (score -1):

DELETE this:

```
PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine
<Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath "/opt/repositories/svn"
        SVNListParentPath on
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Satisfy any
        LimitXMLRequestBody 0
        SVNPathAuthz off
        PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
        PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion Repository"
        Require valid-user
        RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine_db;host=localhost:3306"
        RedmineDbUser "redmine_admin"
        RedmineDbPass "**********"
</Location>
```

And then restart the httpd service

```
[root@iZ23lttzrggZ lmmbao]# service httpd restart
```